# Python, lxml and xpath: returns "[<Element x at 0x29a9998>] rather than expected value

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to scrape TD Asset Management pages (example below; I can't post more than two links) in order to retrieve the "price as on" value, i.e. the dollar amount in this snippet of HTML:

```
<div class="td-layout-grid9 td-layout-column td-layout-column-first">
Price As On: Jun 12, 2015
<br>
<strong>$14.54  </strong>
<strong class="td-copy-red">-0.01 (-0.07%)</strong>
</div>
```

I was hoping to achieve this with Python, requests, lxml, and XPath, which I installed as follows:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install python python-pip python-dev gcc build-essential libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev
pip install lxml
pip install requests
pip install requests[security]
```

Next, to retrieve the page I did this:

```
python
>>> from lxml import html
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get('https://www.tdassetmanagement.com/fundDetails.form?fundId=6320&lang=en')
>>> tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
```

Finally, an attempt was made to retrieve the desired dollar value using the XPath of the relevant element as obtained from Chrome's "Inspect Element" tool:

```
>>> price = tree.xpath('//*[@id="fundCardVO"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/strong[1]')
>>> print price
```

Unfortunately the result is `[<Element strong at 0x29a9998>]` rather than the expected dollar amount `$14.54&nbsp;&nbsp;`.

To ensure that the expected data was retrieved by the initial "requests.get", I ran this:

```
>>> print page.content
```

The result can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/f5C4MFQb.

If I paste the above HTML into this tool: http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi my XPath query `//*[@id="fundCardVO"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/strong[1]` returns the dollar amount as expected.

Any hints or tips as to how I might be able to use Python, lxml, and XPath to retrieve the desired value for this element would be very much appreciated. If there's a completely different way that I could be going about this to obtain the same result I would be interested in that too.

Thanks.

Comment: You're getting a list containing a single `Element`; what's the problem, exactly?

Comment: The problem is that I have no idea how to get the desired value of `$14.54&nbsp;&nbsp;`.

If I do something like `>>> print tree.xpath('//title/text()')` I get the actual title, whereas when I try to get the dollar value I get `[<Element strong at 0x29a9998>]` instead.

I should mention that I'm a complete beginner.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation to find out what an `Element` is, or using e.g. `dir` to find out about its attributes?

Answer (score 2):

After further Googling to find out what elements are (they're lists of things with attributes like `tag` or `text`), followed by more Googling regarding a `UnicodeEncodeError` (see [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)) I was able to obtain my desired value with this:

```
>>> priceelement = tree.xpath('//*[@id="fundCardVO"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/strong[1]')
>>> priceascii = priceelement[0].text
>>> price = priceascii.encode('utf-8')
>>> print price
```

Thanks for nudging me in the right direction jonrsharpe.

I still was not able to determine how to obtain a list of available attributes for the element though, but `tag` and `text` were available.

I went on to get just the number (without the dollar symbol and trailing non-breaking spaces) with this:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.search('[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{2}', price)
>>> price = p.group(0)
>>> print price
```

Comment: *"I still was not able to determine how to obtain a list of available attributes for the element"* - `dir(priceelement[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

use FOR RANGE:
for x in price:
print(x.text)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).